# redirection failing for CGI program

Tags: bash, apache-httpd, html, cgi

I'm trying to redirect the contents of command output to a file in a CGI program. The issue for me is that the output file is not getting created.

The CGI Code snippet is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"

`mysql -u root -predhat -H  -D mysql -e "select host,db from  db;" > output.txt`

 echo "</body>"
 echo "</html>"
```

The CGI script is getting called from an HTML program. Also,I can use `INTO OUTFILE` with a `mysql` command, but I want that output redirection should work for any command.

Ownerships are as follows:

```
  #ls -l /var/www/cgi-bin/example.sh
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 839 Apr 11 21:34 /var/www/cgi-bin/example.sh
```

`# ps -ef | grep httpd
root      2442     1  0 19:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2464  2442  0 19:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2465  2442  0 19:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2466  2442  0 19:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2467  2442  0 19:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2468  2442  0 19:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd`

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: What does your apache error log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off is this script setup so that the user that is running your web server (Apache I'm guessing) can execute it? You can check by looking at the permissions of the script:

```
$ ls -l somescript.cgi
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache apache 1199 Jan 17 20:47 somescript.cgi
```

You'll want the permissions such that anyone can run this or if the script is owned by the user `apache` then at least just the owner can execute it.

If that's the case then I would next focus on the location of the output from the `mysql` command. Apache likely cannot write to the location where `mysql` is attempting to write the file `output`. I'd make that an actual physical location  like this:

```
mysql -u root -predhat -H  -D mysql -e "select host,db from  db;" \
    > /tmp/output.txt
```

Also the backticks are unnecessary, so you can take them out.

Comment: Changing the output location to /tmp directory resolves the issue .

Comment: @ZamaQues - great. Glad that resolved it.